# Enqueue site-banner.css for Wordpress Child Theme to Overwrite Parent Theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have made changes to site-banner.css in my child theme. I want to enqueue the file to overwrite the parent theme.

I tried including this in the functions.php file but I can't see the changes on refresh:

```
function enqueue_child_theme_style() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'site-banner.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_style', 10 );
```

Worth mentioning there is already one enqueue in the functions.php file for style.css. Do I need to add more detail to the function? Also tried changing file location and refrencing it in the uri().

Comment: Have you looked into your source code, to see if your Custom CSS File, is the last stylesheet to be outputted?  The Theme Author could be calling a stylesheet from within a Plugin, for example, which could be overriding your Custom CSS, since it is being loaded after your Custom CSS.  If this is the case, then a rearrangement of priorities will be required.

Comment: This looks to be the case. The custom site-banner1.css starts approx line 300 and the parent equivalent approx line 60. They're three other style sheets that load after the child file but they are not site-banner.css. I downloaded the Asset Queue Manager plugin and curiously my site-banner1.css child file doesn't appear, only the parent. However it is in the source code.

Comment: I should also say that I want these changes to take affect on the mobile site. Not sure if this changes the function in any way.

Comment: It would be easier if we could see the website itself; so that we can see the outputted HTML and establish where the issue may be;  Plugin, Theme, coding error etc.  You can also delete the URL, from here, once the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by using wp_deregister_style:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_alta_styles', 200 );

function load_alta_styles() {

wp_dequeue_style( 'tesseract-site-banner' );
wp_deregister_style( 'tesseract-site-banner' );



wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/site-banner1.css' );



}
```

Thanks for all the input on this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
function enqueue_child_theme_style() {
   wp_dequeue_style( 'child-style' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'site-banner.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_style', 10 );
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you missed slash( `/` ) in this line:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'site-banner.css' );
```

If your file is directly into your child theme directory, then your code will be:

```
function enqueue_child_theme_style() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/site-banner.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_style', 99);
```

Also, make sure, that your handler `child-style` not duplicated. If so and you want to override it( not recommended to keep it same. it'll better to have some other handler name ). This line `wp_dequeue_style( 'some-style' );` we use to preventing stylesheet with handler `some-style` to load in your pages. Then your code will be:

```
function enqueue_child_theme_style() {
   wp_dequeue_style( 'some-style' ); //you can delete this line, if you want to keep the stylesheet in pages. Second line will load below of this stylesheet and will override css rules
   wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/site-banner.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_style', 99);
```

In this line `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_style', 99);` `99` mean, that we added higher `priority`, then is default(10) in wordpress. This will load your stylesheet later, then other stylesheets, which usign lower priority.

**Edit**

Use this function to remove `site-banner.css` from your parent theme, and call your own `site-banner1.css` stylesheet:

```
function enqueue_child_theme_style() {
   wp_dequeue_style( 'site-banner' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'child-banner', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/site-banner.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_style', 99);
```

Comment: Tried the above code. I renamed the child sheet site-banner1.css, interestingly I now get a mixture of the parent site-banner.css and the child sitebanner1.css in the chrome dev tools>elements>styles console on page load. Do I need to add more to wp_dequeue_style to completely remove the parent site-banner.css?

Comment: I went into parent theme functions.php and copied the site-banner.css enqueue into the child theme dequeue as mentioned in this vid but still no luck. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yY85JbWh7qs

Comment: @Pete can you provide function, where you find enqueue of parent themes `site-banner.css`? it may use some other hook, which fired later, then we trying to dequeue it

Comment: Here is my most recent attempt: function enqueue_child_theme_style() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'tesseract-site-banner', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/css/site-banner.css'); //you can delete this line, if you want to keep the stylesheet in pages. Second line will load below of this stylesheet and will override css rules
   wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/site-banner1.css', array( 'tesseract-site-banner' ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_style', 99999);

Comment: Worth mentioning there is another function in the functions.php file that enqueues style.css to the child, this seems to work ok, here is the code: if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array(  ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );

Comment: I see. you're trying to call 2 stylesheets: `site-banner.css`, and `site-banner1.css`. which one of them you need?

Comment: site-banner1.css is the modified version I need, I want it to overwrite site-banner.css.

Comment: @Pete but do you need to serve `site-banner.css` in the website? or you need to remove it?

Comment: I can remove site-banner.css from the website (parent theme) and use site-banner1.css from the child theme as it is mostly the same script. Do I just need to delete site-banner.css using ftp?

Comment: @Pete I updated answer. but in this line `wp_dequeue_style( 'site-banner' );` the `site-banner` may not be a handler for that stylesheet. Dig into parent theme and find, where is calling parent themes `site-banner.css` file. there should be something like this ` wp_enqueue_style( 'some-string', get_template_directory_uri().'/site-banner.css' );`, or `wp_register_style( 'some-string', get_template_directory_uri().'/site-banner.css' );` and provide that line of code. I'll update my answer after it

Comment: Double checked the handler and its 'tesseract-site-banner'. Here is my most recent attempt but still no luck:  function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'tesseract-site-banner';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/site-banner.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/site-banner1.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/site-banner1.css' )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles',99999 );

Comment: I'm trying to remove the white header on the mobile version of the site, its in the #masthead_TesseractTheme id header. Let me know when your online and I will post the url.

Comment: I have gone through the source code to find the last style id before the closing head tag. It is a plugin 'tt-easy-google-font-styles' which i included in the array to try and force site-banner1.css to load last. Not working, any ideas?

Comment: Here is the code:

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() { $parent_style = 'tesseract-site-banner'; 
wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/site-banner.css' ); 
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/site-banner1.css', 
array( $parent_style , 'wp-custom-css' )
); } 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles',99999 );